# SPSS output modify 'select all except (tables)' still selects custom tables

Tags: spss

When I run this syntax in SPSS:

output modify 
/select all except (Tables)
/deleteobject delete=yes.

my custom tables still get deleted. Do you have any idea whether this is a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

TABLES is a generic term for all objects of type table, which includes custom tables output.  You can do what you want with OMS using syntax like this.

```
oms select all /exceptif subtypes='Custom Table'/destination viewer=no.
```

CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=educ DISPLAY=DEFAULT
  /TABLE educ [C][COUNT F40.0]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=educ ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE MISSING=EXCLUDE
  /CRITERIA CILEVEL=95.

DESCRIPTIVES VARIABLES=bdate educ id jobcat jobtime
  /STATISTICS=MEAN STDDEV MIN MAX.
omsend.